# AutoMapper non-static conversion from static - MapperConfiguration, CreateMapper

Tags: c#, automapper, non-static

I'm moving from a mixture of v2 & v4 AutoMapper static coding on .NET Framework 4, to version 6.0.1 using .NET Framework 4.6.2.  I am running into problems in my conversion development under Visual Studio 2015.

```
var dummy = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<DateTime,string>());
```

Visual Studio tells me that MapperConfiguration.MapperConfiguration(Action<IMapperConfigurationExpression> configure) (+1 overload) 
Constructor 'MapperConfiguration' has 0 parameter(s) but is invoked with 1 argument(s).

When I code the next line:

```
var dmy1 = dummy.CreateMapper();
```

Visual Studio tells me that IMapper MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper() (+1 overload) Cannot resolve symbol CreateMapper.

This is all basic non-static stuff, and I could use another pair of eyes giving me a heads up on what I'm missing.  I'm thinking once I solve the problem with the first line of code, the other problem will go away.  Ideas?

Comment: Apologies, I'm converting from static to non-static code approach

Comment: I've created a new WinForm project using .NET 4.6.2 framework, and used NuGet to add AutoMapper to my project.  The problems I mentioned above are not present.  So it must be something in my solution causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem goes away when I restart Visual Studio.  There must have been something residual in the VS instance causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

I has the same problem after Edmx update. The problem goes away after Visual Studio  restart.